# Deciding an algorithm's basic operation; if the operation occurs at two different parts, are they counted as the same basic operation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I've come across the idea of basic operations and I'm trying to grasp how to select one from an algorithm.Take for instance this algorithm:

```
doX (int[]l)
{
    int n;
    n = l.length;

        int first, second;
        int temp;

        for (first=0; first < n-1 && l[first] < l[first+1]; first++);

        if (first < n-1)
        {
            for (second = n-1; l[second-1] < l[second]; second--);

            temp = l[first];
            l[first] = l[second];
            l[second] = temp;
        }
}
```

From this, it is clear that comparison is the key aspect, but there are two comparisons made here. Should I take the comparison in the outer loop, "for (first=0; first < n-1 && l[first] < l[first+1]; first++);" and the comparison in the innter loop, "for (second = n-1; l[second-1] < l[second]; second--);" to be two different operations? Or, should I count them as the same operation?

Comment: You can count whatever you like. The beauty of big-O notation is that it often doesn't matter what, exactly, you're counting.

Comment: @rcgldr Would they still be considered different operations if I only examined the comparison parts of the for loops (just taking the A[x] < A[y] parts)? Or, do I need to include every part of that loop when looking at basic operations?

Comment: @rcgldr Apologies for the follow-up, need to clarify one last thing. Do I need to choose a full loop as my basic operation? Or, is it possible to say comparison is my basic operation, then examine both instances of it when checking the number of operations?

Comment: I deleted my prior comments. `Basic operations` are: add, subtract, multiply, divide, compare, input, output, ... . Note that the code is not a sort although it's tagged as a sort. It could be modified to be a [shaker sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_shaker_sort).